# $http.get pass encodeURIComponent to Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass some special characters( _ + - ) to my web api, now I know I have to use `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript which does encode them.   But when I pass the encoded url to http.get it is throwing an exception:

The get request code:

```
    find: function (id) {
        var scope = this;
        var urlApi = webapi_base_url + model_url;

        id = encodeURIComponent(id);

        return $http.get(urlApi + id)
                    .then(function (response) {

                        if (response.data.success && response.data.exists) {
                            //logger.info('Successfully found model', '', 'Success');
                        }
                        else {
                            if (showLogger)
                                logger.error(response.data.error, '', 'Error');
                        }

                        return response.data;
                    })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                scope.WebFailed('get', err);
                    })
    }
```

For example I want to pass the values `a+` to my web api, the url is:

> https://localhost:44310/api/v1/model/a%26

The following error is thrown:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44310/api/v1/model/a%26. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59242' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

When I send the value of 'a' to the web API it is fine and no problems:

The web api code

```
[Route("{description}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] string description)
{
Model model = await _repository.Model().Get().Where(x => x.Description == description).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (model == null)
    return Ok(new { success = false, exists = false, error = "Could not find model" });

return Ok(new { success = true, exists = true });
}
```

I think when I have encoded the uri the web api cannot find the path and is throwing an exception.

Any ideas how I can fix the web api to allow encoded characters.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `$http.get` method call?

Comment: Could you use $http.post and pass it in the body? Then you don't have to worry about encoding.

Comment: You are right, I could use http.post but I am not posting so isn't it right that I should use http.get?